# Handling Subversion external links inside other external links

Tags: svn, svn-externals

We would like to use the subversion external link ability, but have hit a wall on getting external links to work in the way that we need them given that we probably have an abnormal arrangement of source.

The use case is such, we have an external library 1 and library 2. Library 1 can be built by itself (C++ libraries), without Library 2. Library 2 however has to be built inside Library 1's source tree. If you check-out the code we have a tree like such:

~/my_checkout/trunk/extern/library1/library2

Now, above, library1 is an external link to a source tree. The directory library2 we would like to be an external link to another source tree.

We have projects that don't need library2 (as library 2 is quite large) so we can't create an external link inside library 1's source tree. Also projects using library 1 are long in production so they are not willing to change there checkout procedures to accommodate any checkout differences (unfortunately).

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it safe to assume a server-side structure like: `^/Projects/Library1/`, `^/Projects/Library2/` and `^/Projects/MainApp/` where `MainApp` has an external to `Library1` and another external to `Library2`?

Comment: Pretty much yes - slight mod is that there is an extern directory where they are externalized to (^/Projects/MainApp/extern/[extern_to_Library1] and ^/Projects/MainApp/extern/[extern_to_Library2]). Other difference (not that I think it makes a difference) is MainApp and LibraryX are in different repo addresses (but LibraryX are stored in the same repo)

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading: `~/my_checkout/trunk/extern/library1/library2` implies that the `extern/` folder has an external pointing to `library1/`, which itself has an external pointing to `library2/`

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I re-read the question. I think the best solution is to have two separate externals pointing to `Library1` and `Library2`, and ensuring that `Library1` is built before `Library2`. If `Library2` isn't needed by your `MainApp`, simply don't add an external to it.

Comment: The problem is that `Library 2` code needs to be inside `Library 1`'s source tree. So is there a way of getting this without having two `svn co` operations?

Comment: Oh, I think I got the dependencies mixed up. So, `Library1` depends on `Library2` for it to build successfully? Would you be able to have `Library1` reference `Library2` as a built artifact (a .DLL, I presume), or do you need the actual source of `Library2` inside `Library1`?

Comment: The dependency you had was correct. `Library1` can build fine without `Library2`. `Library2` needs `Library1` to build. `Library2` also needs source, makefiles, includes, etc. from `Library1` and the way the vendor has written the makefiles, they are relative directories (e.g. include ../../common/include.inc). This is why they need to be nested in order to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this was not a clever question. We found that you can actually set two externals on the same base root directory, just with a different local paths.

So in Tortoise SVN, you can add two externals with different but nested paths on the same root directory. I haven't done this with the command line but it should be possible as well.

After this the properties are:

```
externs$ svn propget svn:externals .
http://test.example.com/project/library1/trunk library1
http://test.example.com/project/library2/trunk library1/library2
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Yes, I think this is the way to go. The second external is optional: only those applications that need `Library2` will have that external, and `Library2` will build successfully because it is located within `Library1`.